# Sml type confusion

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have this function:

```
fun x (u,v,w) = (u::[v])::w;
```

Which gets a return type of

```
fn: 'a * 'a * 'a list list -> 'a list list
```

Could anyone explain to me how this type is generated from the function? Thank you!

Edit: Also, how would I call this function?

Comment: You should not replace your question with a completely different question after someone has answered it.

Comment: I have rolled this back to the original question. If you want to ask a new question, please do that instead of editing this one.

Comment: @OP: That's what is called type inference. You may have just asked people to explain you what type inference is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::` takes two arguments -- one on the left and one on the right. If its left argument is of type `t`, then its right argument must be of type `t list`.

Thus, `::` has type `('a * 'a list) -> 'a list`, as the `t` is arbitrary, and is therefore represented by an `'a`.

When you have the code `(u::[v])`, therefore, you are telling SML that `u : t` and `'v : t` for some type `t`. This expression is then a `t list`, and so to use it as the left argument to `::`, the right argument, `w`, must have type `t list list`.

This then gives that the type of `(u::[v])::w` is `t list list` for some `t`.

In summary:
`u : t`
`v : t`
`w : t list`
`(u::[v])::w : t list list`,

all for some type `t`.

Thus, the type of `x` is `('a * 'a * 'a list) -> 'a list list`, as `t` is arbitrary.

To call this function, you could do something like `x(1,2,[3,4])`, which would give the list `[[1,2],[3,4]]`.

Comment: When I call it using your example, I get a domain error. Says operand: int * int * int* list